# Arguably- does the adverb carries "what I am saying is unarguable" connotation

Tags: adverbs, expression-choice, pragmatics

*Arguably-* “I’m a little confused about the usage of this word.

- "Roger Federer is **arguably** the best tennis player ever.

This is what I heard in a conversation.

> My point is does the statement seem to imply that ***what they’re
>   saying is unarguable***,  and **exactly correct** in their opinion. or
>   the use of adverb is daring you to argue with that statement.

Comment: No, *arguably* means I'm admitting that some  people might consider what I'm saying to be debatable but I'm saying it here.

Comment: See also [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/5684/32) on ELL.

Comment: Roger Federer is arguably .... ever- implies that a solid argument can be made in favor of Mr Federer. Use arguably when you want to "emphasize or back up" a statement or opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers.. I upvoted your answer on a similar question. Could not have found a better.  Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Arguably](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/arguably)* means

> It may be argued (used to qualify the statement of an opinion or belief):
>   *she is arguably the greatest woman tennis player of all time*

In your sentence means

> *Some people may argue that Roger Federer is the best tennis player ever*

The speaker's position is not in opposition to this view and considers it possible, but is not insisting on it.